# How to create a column with hour interval from two columns in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

i have the following dataframe structure:

```
exec_start_date  exec_finish_date  hour_start  hour_finish session_qtd 
2020-03-01       2020-03-02          22           0            1
2020-03-05       2020-03-05          22           23           3 
2020-03-03       2020-03-04          18           7            4
2020-03-07       2020-03-07          18           18           2
```

As you can see above, i have three situations of sessions execution:

**1)** Start in one day and finish in another day with different hours

**2)** Start in one day and finish in the same day with different hours

**3)** Start in one day and finish in the same day with same hours

I need to create a column filling the interval between **hour_start** and **hour_finish** and create another column with execution date. Then:

- If a session starts in one day and finish in another day, the hours executed in the **start date** need to be filled with **exec_start_date** and the hours executed in the **following day** need to be filled with the **exec_finish_date**.

So, a intermediary dataset would be like this:

```
exec_start_date  exec_finish_date  hour_start  hour_finish session_qtd   hour_interval
    2020-03-01       2020-03-02          22           0            1       [22,23,0]
    2020-03-05       2020-03-05          22           23           3       [22,23]
    2020-03-03       2020-03-04          20           3            4       [20,21,22,23,0,1,2,3]
    2020-03-07       2020-03-07          18           18           2       [18]
```

And the final dataset would be like this:

```
exec_date  session_qtd  hour_interval
2020-03-01     1             22
2020-03-01     1             23
2020-03-02     1             0
2020-03-05     3             22
2020-03-05     3             23
2020-03-03     4             20
2020-03-03     4             21
2020-03-03     4             22
2020-03-03     4             23
2020-03-04     4             0
2020-03-04     4             1
2020-03-04     4             2
2020-03-04     4             3
2020-03-07     2             18
```

I have tried to create the interval with ***np.arange*** but didn't work properly to all cases, specially with the cases that start in one day and finish in another day.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make df dtype string**

```
df=df.astype(str)
```

**Concat date with hour and coerce to datetime**

```
df['exec_start_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['exec_start_date'].str.cat(df['hour_start'], sep=' ')+ ':00:00')
df['exec_finish_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['exec_finish_date'].str.cat(df['hour_finish'], sep=' ')+ ':00:00')
```

**Derive hourly periods between the start and end datetime**

```
df['date'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.period_range(start=pd.Period(x['exec_start_date'],freq='H'),  end=pd.Period(x['exec_finish_date'],freq='H'), freq='H').hour.tolist(), axis = 1)
```

**Explode date to achieve outcome**

```
df.explode('date')
```

**Can skip last step by exploding after deriving hourly periods as follows**

```
df.assign(date=df.apply(lambda x: pd.period_range(start=pd.Period(x['exec_start_date'],freq='H'),  end=pd.Period(x['exec_finish_date'],freq='H'), freq='H').hour.tolist(), axis = 1)).explode('date')
```

**Outcome**

```
 exec_start_date    exec_finish_date hour_start hour_finish session_qtd  \
0 2020-03-01 22:00:00 2020-03-02 00:00:00         22           0           1   
0 2020-03-01 22:00:00 2020-03-02 00:00:00         22           0           1   
0 2020-03-01 22:00:00 2020-03-02 00:00:00         22           0           1   
1 2020-03-05 22:00:00 2020-03-05 23:00:00         22          23           3   
1 2020-03-05 22:00:00 2020-03-05 23:00:00         22          23           3   
2 2020-03-03 18:00:00 2020-03-04 07:00:00         18           7           4   
2 2020-03-03 18:00:00 2020-03-04 07:00:00         18           7           4   
2 2020-03-03 18:00:00 2020-03-04 07:00:00         18           7           4   
2 2020-03-03 18:00:00 2020-03-04 07:00:00         18           7           4   
2 2020-03-03 18:00:00 2020-03-04 07:00:00         18           7           4   
2 2020-03-03 18:00:00 2020-03-04 07:00:00         18           7           4   
2 2020-03-03 18:00:00 2020-03-04 07:00:00         18           7           4   
2 2020-03-03 18:00:00 2020-03-04 07:00:00         18           7           4   
2 2020-03-03 18:00:00 2020-03-04 07:00:00         18           7           4   
2 2020-03-03 18:00:00 2020-03-04 07:00:00         18           7           4   
2 2020-03-03 18:00:00 2020-03-04 07:00:00         18           7           4   
2 2020-03-03 18:00:00 2020-03-04 07:00:00         18           7           4   
2 2020-03-03 18:00:00 2020-03-04 07:00:00         18           7           4   
2 2020-03-03 18:00:00 2020-03-04 07:00:00         18           7           4   
3 2020-03-07 18:00:00 2020-03-07 18:00:00         18          18           2   

  date  
0   22  
0   23  
0    0  
1   22  
1   23  
2   18  
2   19  
2   20  
2   21  
2   22  
2   23  
2    0  
2    1  
2    2  
2    3  
2    4  
2    5  
2    6  
2    7  
3   18
```

Comment: @Ysabelle Sousa was this helpful?

Comment: Worked like a charm to hour interval. But it's missing the part of exec date column. How can i assign the right exec date of each hour in just one column, like described above?

Comment: Your question not clear. Why are you dropping `session_qtd==3` from the final output. In plain English, how do you come up with the final output from what I have so far?

Comment: About session_qtd==3 i was my mistake. I wrote it wrong. I mixed your answer with @Ben Pap exec date extraction and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Are you happy to upvote so that people can confidently use your question and my answer in future. Gave you an upvote

Answer (score 2):

So the way I would do this is to get the full dates to get the time interval, then just pull the hours from that range. `np.arange` will not work because hours loop.

```
#Create two new temp columns that calculate have the full start and end date
df['start'] = df['exec_start_date'].astype(str) + " " + df['hour_start'].astype(str) + ":00.000"
df['end'] = df['exec_finish_date'].astype(str) + " " + df['hour_finish'].astype(str) + ":00.000"

#Convert them both to datetimes
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

#Apply a function to get your range
df['date'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['start'], x['end'], freq='H').tolist(), axis = 1)

#explode new date column to get 1 column for all the created interval dates
df = df.explode(column = 'date')

#Make two new columns based on your final requested table based on new column
df['exec_date'] = df['date'].dt.date
df['hour_interval'] = df['date'].dt.hour

#Make a copy of the columns you wanted in a new df
df2 = df[['exec_date','session_qtd','hour_interval']].copy()
```

Comment: It works with a small dataset. But when i apply it to my whole dataset (900K lines) i get memory error in apply line.

Comment: Try using @wwnde’s apply line, and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without converting the date fields:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ss = '''
exec_start_date,exec_finish_date,hour_start,hour_finish,session_qtd
2020-03-01,2020-03-02,22,0,1
2020-03-05,2020-03-05,22,23,3
2020-03-03,2020-03-04,18,7,4
2020-03-07,2020-03-07,18,18,2
'''.strip()

with open('data.csv','w') as f: f.write(ss)

########## main script #############

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['hour_start'] = df['hour_start'].astype('int')
df['hour_finish'] = df['hour_finish'].astype('int')

# get hour list, group by day
df['hour_interval'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(range(x[2],x[3]+1)) if x[0]==x[1] else [(101,) + tuple(range(x[2],24))]+[(102,)+tuple(range(0,x[3]+1))], axis=1)

lst_col = 'hour_interval'

# split day group to separate rows
hrdf = pd.DataFrame({
      col:np.repeat(df[col].values, df[lst_col].str.len())
      for col in df.columns.drop(lst_col)}
    ).assign(**{lst_col:np.concatenate(df[lst_col].values)})[df.columns]

# choose start\end day
hrdf['exec_date'] = hrdf.apply(lambda x: x[0] if type(x[5]) is int or x[5][0] == 101 else x[1], axis=1)

# remove day indicator
hrdf['hour_interval'] = hrdf['hour_interval'].apply(lambda x: [x] if type(x) is int else list(x[1:]))

# split hours to separate rows
df = hrdf
hrdf = pd.DataFrame({
      col:np.repeat(df[col].values, df[lst_col].str.len())
      for col in df.columns.drop(lst_col)}
    ).assign(**{lst_col:np.concatenate(df[lst_col].values)})[df.columns]

# columns for final output
df_final = hrdf[['exec_date','session_qtd','hour_interval']]

print(df_final.to_string(index=False))
```

Output

```
  exec_date  session_qtd  hour_interval
 2020-03-01            1             22
 2020-03-01            1             23
 2020-03-02            1              0
 2020-03-05            3             22
 2020-03-05            3             23
 2020-03-03            4             18
 2020-03-03            4             19
 2020-03-03            4             20
 2020-03-03            4             21
 2020-03-03            4             22
 2020-03-03            4             23
 2020-03-04            4              0
 2020-03-04            4              1
 2020-03-04            4              2
 2020-03-04            4              3
 2020-03-04            4              4
 2020-03-04            4              5
 2020-03-04            4              6
 2020-03-04            4              7
 2020-03-07            2             18
```

Comment: It's not applying the right interval. It's assigning many hours for simple cases, like one hour difference for same day session execution